# Remembering Lists in backtracking

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, backtracking

I am working on a question that requires me to generate an array that includes all of the difference values. Backtracking naturally seemed to be the method to use here but im having some issues with the fundamentals of backtracking.
There is a choiceList at each node, from which I'll have to pick an element and test the condition.

But say the condition fails(at some leaf node) and I backtrack, how do I **remember** the `choiceList` at that stage?

My Code:

```
def arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i):
    proto[-1] = N

    if None not in proto:
        lst = diffChecker(proto)
        if 0 in lst or 1 in lst: #now we backtrack
            print(f"{proto} is not a solution\n")
            return
        else:
            print(f"{proto} is a solution\n")

            return

    if not choiceList: #choicelist is empty
        print(f"{proto} contains None\n")
        return


    if proto[i] is None:
        proto[i] = choiceList[0]
        choiceList.pop(0)
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i+1)
        proto[i] = None
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i)
    else:
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i+1)
```

[photo of the subspace if it helps][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC7DP.jpg The boxed lists are the choiceLists.

The main issue im encountering is after backtracking at the [0,1,2,5,6] node, the ChoiceList turns empty. I want it to revert back to WHAT IT WAS THEN. So when ill be backtracking from [0,1,2,5,6] to [0,1,2,None,6], it should detect that since the choiceList is empty, all possible combinations here have been explored and should back track again to [0,1,None,None,6] and here the choiceList should revert back to {2,3,4,5} - {2} = {3,4,5} since {2} has been used till now.

I realize im not making this terribly clear, I apologize. What I NEED are insights on how to perform backtracking in these kinds of problems?

EDIT-
the diffChecker function (checks for success/failure of the condition in question)

```
def diffChecker(lst):
    result = [0]*(lst[-1]+1)
    dontCount = set()
    result[0] = 2
    result[-1] = 2
    for i in range(1,lst[-1]):#diff_Values
        dontCount = set()
        for j in lst:
            if j == None:
                continue
            if((j + i) in lst and frozenset((j,j+i)) not in dontCount):
                result[i] += 1
                dontCount.add(frozenset((j,j+i)))
            elif((j-i) in lst and frozenset((j,j-i)) not in dontCount):
                result[i] += 1
                dontCount.add(frozenset((j,j-i)))
    return result
```

Driver code-

```
#driver/main code-
n = int(input("Enter array size: "))
N = n+1 # dynamic upper limit
proto = [None]*n #length of resultant array is fixed
proto[0] = 0 #first element is always 0
proto[-1] = N
diff_table = [0]*(N+1)
diff_table[-1] = 2 #in actuality it is 1, but for efficiency purposes we've put = 2
diff_table[0] = 2
current_diff = 1 # since diff val of 0 is already present twice - (0-0) & (N-N)
choiceList = []
for i in range(1,N):
    choiceList.append(i)
i = 0
arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i)
```

Sample input/output scenario(current)-

```
Enter array size: 5
#now, we try to generate all array combinations that satisfy the diffChecker function from this via backtracking

[0, 1, 2, 3, 6] is not a solution

[0, 1, 2, 4, 6] is not a solution


[0, 1, 2, 4, 6] is not a solution

[0, 1, 2, 5, 6] is not a solution


[0, 1, 2, None, 6] contains None

[0, 1, None, None, 6] contains None
#from this part on, the code should not backtrack again. Refer to the attached picture on how exactly I'm trying to fill up the None spots

#expected- [0,1,3,None,None,6] ->(advance) [0,1,3,4,None,6] ->....

[0, None, None, None, 6] contains None
```

Comment: To be honest I've always found that python was pretty terrible for backtracking, compared to other languages. The way python handles variables is different from most other languages and for backtracking in particular it can be very annoying.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the intention is of the function. Can you add driver code that calls this function on a concrete, but small, example input? And can you indicate what is the expected output for it, and what you get instead? Can you also provide the definition of the function `diffChecker`, so we can actually run your code?

Comment: @trincot does this help? kindly look into it
thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding more code, but I am completely lost what problem this code is supposed to solve. I don't understand a thing of what `diffChecker` is doing, so I'll pass on this question.

Comment: @trincot ah no problem. How about treating diffChecker as just some function which checks whether to accept or reject the leaf solution? The issue im facing is in performing backtracking

Comment: Yes, I understand your question is about backtracking, where I'm sure I can help out, but this algorithm is beyond my understanding. Can you not rewrite your question with a simple recursive algorithm -- that still has the problem you want to ask about?

Comment: @trincot ill certainly do that. give me a while
and thank you

Comment: 1st All of the data is kept on the stack. 2nd when you first encounter a choicepoint you logically mark the stack. Then if you have to backtrack to the choicepoint you just clear the stack back to the choicepoint, use the next option at the choicepoint and continue. Make sense? The next question you will now have to answer is how to deal with multiple choicepoints and which one to pick on backtracking, am I am not talking multiple options for a single choicepoint, I am talking about multiple choicepoints active at one time.

Comment: Also know that list are just syntactic sugar for a tree that represents a list and this is how the list should be stored on the stack so that as elements are added to the list they can also be removed as elements when backtracking. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There basically two strategies for remembering previous states for backtracking:

1. Do not modify states. Instead, pass a completely *new* copy of the state to the next level.  This is what you do when states are small and simple.
2. Modify the state before passing it to the next level, but remember *undo* information and undo the modification when backtracking.  This is what you do when states are too big or complicated to make new copies every time.

You can mix and match these approaches for different parts of the state.  If looks like you should use the undo strategy for the array modifications:

```
    if proto[i] is None:

        # modify state and remember undo information
        protoUndo = proto[i]
        proto[i] = choiceList[0]
        choiceListUndo = choiceList.pop(0)

        # pass state to next level
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i+1)
        proto[i] = None
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i)

        # undo modifications
        proto[i] = protoUndo
        choiceList.insert(0, choiceListUndo)
    else:
        arrayGen(n,N,proto,choiceList,i+1)
```